# Normal oriented elliptical shapes (surfels) using point sprites

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I am trying to reproduce this effect with point sprites (given vertices with a position and normal).

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img36/7057/5t7b.jpg]

Essentially discarding fragments of a point sprite, dependent on the normal of that point, to produce an an elliptical shape tangent to the point normal (essentially approximated ortho projection of a 3D circle to a 2D ellipse).

From the equation I found d = -(n.x/n.z)*x-(n.y/n.z)*y, where a fragment is discarded if the world space distance from the point center to a point (x,y,d) is greater that the disk radius (as indicated by the text above the image).

I am trying to figure the right way of doing this in my GLSL vertex and fragment shaders, using point sprites.

in my  shaders I am doing something like this, which isn't working:

```
//vertex shader
#version 400


layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;

out vec3 Color;
flat out vec3 PtPosition;
flat out vec3 PtNormal;
out vec3 FragPosition;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform float heightMin;
uniform float heightMax;
uniform bool invertGrad = false;


uniform mat4 MV;
uniform float pointSize;
uniform float viewportDim;


float perspPtSize(vec3 ptPos, mat4 mv, float ptWorldSize, float viewportDim)
{
  vec3 posEye = vec3(mv * vec4(ptPos, 1.0));
  return ptWorldSize * (viewportDim / length(posEye));
}

void main()
{
  Color = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
  PtPosition = vec3(MV * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0));
  FragPosition = PtPosition; 
  PtNormal = vec3(MV * vec4(VertexNormal,1.0));
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);


  gl_PointSize = perspPtSize(VertexPosition.xyz,MV,pointSize,viewportDim);
}


//fragment shader
#version 400

layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 Color;
flat in vec3 PtPosition;
flat in vec3 PtNormal;

void main() 
{
  vec2 ptC = gl_PointCoord- vec2(0.5);
  float depth = -PtNormal.x/PtNormal.z*ptC.x - 
                 PtNormal.y/PtNormal.z*ptC.y; 
  float sqrMag = ptC.x*ptC.x + ptC.y*ptC.y + depth*depth; 

  if(sqrMag > 0.25) 
  { discard; } 
  else 
  { fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0); }
}
```

Has anyone successfully implemented an effect like this? I tried doing this in world space as well but ended up getting incorrect results, I figured if i left it all in point sprite expressed space it might be easier.

I think I am missing some basic concept for doing this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, `gl_PointCoord` is in screen space, and your normals are (sort of) in view space (so not everything is being done in the "space expressed by `gl_PointCoord`").

I would suggest you use a normal matrix (transpose inverse of the top-left 3x3 sub-matrix of `MV`) to transform your normals instead of the ModelView matrix because they will not rotate properly otherwise. You also need to re-normalize your normals after doing this if there is any scaling in your `MV` matrix.

On that note, if you are going to multiply your normal by a 4x4 matrix for whatever reason, do not set the `W` coordinate to **1.0**. **W=1.0** is for spatial vectors (e.g. vectors where ***translation*** actually makes sense), and normals are directional; use **0.0** instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to change one minus into a plus like:

```
float depth = -PtNormal.x/PtNormal.z*ptC.x + PtNormal.y/PtNormal.z*ptC.y;
```

seems like there was one (-) too much. hope that helps

(i was reading the book and came across the same problem... better late than never i guess ;-) )